# What's the best way to do time versioning of a neo4j node?

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a bunch of nodes with varying relationships between both, now if I want to know the history of changes that has happened to a particular node, say a new relationship got added on 31st Oct, how to get those? Should I have to follow temporal versioning by following a proper data model or is there any other way to retrieve the data for the already created nodes/relationships?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to ‘versioning’ is this one : https://neo4j.com/graphgist/network-versions

I prefer this kind of approach over the ones that use timestamps because the former optimally use the built in node adjacency and the latter often requires more “opening” of nodes and rels to check any timestamp values.